# How to add a field in fs.chunks collection in MongoDB using Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using GirdFs to store images in my local directory to MongoDB Collection.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from imutils import paths
import gridfs

client = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = client.dbs 
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)


imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("images"))

for i, imagePath in enumerate(imagePaths):
    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]  # to get the name of the directory
    fs.put(open(imagePath, 'rb'))
```

The above code creates Two collections `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`.
It creates metadata in `fs.files` which contains fields

- _id
- md5
- chunkSize
- length
- uploadDate

So in my Images Folder there are subfolders and I want to save name of the subfolders(stored in *name* variable) into `fs.files`.

How can I achieve this?

I checked the documentation for `put` method [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs). It takes data argument and **kwargs. I am not aware of if this can help to add new field as no details available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the file-level options described in [Gridfs Specification](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#the-files-collection) can be passed as keyword arguments.

For example, you can set the filename like so

```
fs.put(open(imagePath, 'rb'), filename="foo")
```

Any other fields not available in the file document spec can be store in the file document metadata field. 
The metadata field can hold any type so whatever you store here is left to your care.

```
fs.put(open(imagePath, 'rb'), metadata={"subfolder": "foo-subfolder"})
```